# NameError: name 'PathOrStr' is not defined

Tags: python, kaggle

i was working on kaggle and check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai?scriptVersionId=11220630&cellId=27) project. and i am getting an error even saying

[1](https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai?scriptVersionId=11220630&cellId=27): https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai "NameError: name 'PathOrStr' is not defined" on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/qitvision/a-complete-ml-pipeline-fast-ai?scriptVersionId=11220630&cellId=27) CELL. i imported all the required libraries like fastai.vision and others. the code is

```
class MyImageItemList(**ImageList**):
    def open(self, fn:**PathOrStr**)->Image:
        pass
```

i.e. i changed **ImageList** into **ImageDataLoaders** becuase i am using fastai 2.3 and there is no ImageList in version 2 and above, but the project on kaggle is using fastai 1.0 and it is using ImageList